# Who killed Tom?

Tags: cipher, mystery

The date is 20/2/2018. You are a detective and have been contacted by the police officer to help to crack a case. "Our CEO, Tom has been murdered in his room just now. The only suspects are Norman, Hana, and Anthony. The only clue we could find was the message left on his computer: *cftgbhu*." the police officer said. You inspect the room more and don't seem to see any more clues.

*Who is the murderer?*

Comment: You'd think that if Tom wanted to tell the world who his murderer was, and he had, you know, a computer in front of him, he could have just typed the killer's name? :/

Comment: @Xenocacia If Blckknght is right, he did ... or tried to ... sort of. :P

Comment: what about @bass answer police officers don't have CEO. I think it is perfect answer are your question would we wrong.

Comment: I think LAU WAN is framing poor Norman.

Comment: I am **not** framing him! :( Are **you** framing me that I am framing him?

Comment: It was the cat.

Comment: @Rubio Unless I'm blind the top voted answer was accepted yesterday. Though I still think the cat did it...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Hm - the checkmark didn't show up when I refreshed the page. Thanks for the heads-up.  (I agree about the cat. Cats are evil.)

Comment: If someone was killing me the last thing I would do is sit at my desk typing gibberish or coming up with a coded message. Id grab the keyboard and swing it like a madman.

Comment: I'm not sure but they must have beat the crap out of him with his keyboard.

Comment: The pattern on the keyboard is a sideways Z. The Z is the mark of Zorro, played by Anthony Hopkins. So Anthony was the killer.

Comment: Wait, what? I'm dead?

Comment: And why not write message `Norman` instead of `cftgbhu`? If Norman can see his name and delete it, he can see strange message and delete it as well.

Comment: @i486, the puzzle wouldn't be a puzzle if it was like this. :P

Comment: @JamesLawruk well, rotate Z and you make N, which stands for **Norman**...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> Norman is most likely to be the killer. The letters CFTGBHU are arranged in the shape of an *N* (albeit a very slanted one) on a QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: You could equally say it's a slanted H.

Comment: @Richard I think it is about the direction/order of the code. To make an H, the code would look more like UHBJOKM or UHBHJKOKM.

Comment: @PL457 It definitely is. Think about how most people can't type without looking at their keyboard. Detectives are not exempt from this. Then try typing those characters one after another. It'd instantly stand out to anyone working with the police.

Comment: @Richard Or even "N"-thony. :P

Comment: Even I think Norman, but for a different reason. In the clue "cftgbhu", the letters "t" and "h" are present in Hana (H) and Anthony (T - Tony - short name for Anthony), where as Norman doesn't have anyone of these letters. May be the murderer wanted to give an inverse clue!

Answer (score 90):

There was no murder, the police officer is trying to set you up. (Possibly trying to prove that you would be ready to accuse someone of murder based on a garbled message on a computer.)

> Police officers don't have CEOs.

Comment: [This may disagree with your solution (linked to avoid spoilers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_enforcement_officer) - but I do still really like this take on it.

Comment: I feel like that would be a pretty flimsy setup.. wouldn't the detective know? (not that it's any more flimsy than the accepted answer)

Comment: I feel like it's not unreasonable for a police officer to refer to a CEO involved in a case somehow as "our CEO" in a similar manner to "our witness," "our suspect," or "our waiter" (if something happened at a restaurant, for example).   Not necessarily saying that he was literally the CEO *of the police*.

Comment: @Bilkokuya I don't believe that people in that category of employment would be sitting at an office desk with a keyboard.

Answer (score 80):

It's clearly

> Anthony

Because

> The murderer would see the murder victim mashing their hand on the keyboard and writing something. Even if the murder victim did not write the murderer's name, the murderer will delete the text anyway. The murderer doesn't need to understand how the text implicates them to guess that it implicates them.

Therefore

> The text was written by the murderer to frame someone.

As

> The text could spell either an N or a H, the text was written by Anthony, who didn't care whether the text led to Norman or Hana being jailed.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of that! I clearly need to think about my names in puzzles.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a smart answer.

Comment: Love how this is broken into 4 parts, it reads like the climax of a Phoenix Wright case :)

Comment: @JackCasey https://youtu.be/Y3R8tkvlAlk

Answer (score 14):

Things are crystal clear. The murderer is

> The police officer

because

> He stated that the murder happened "just now" and he must have been in Tom's room just before to see the writing on Tom's computer.

Answer (score 12):

How about

> Anthony , as `Anthony` and `CFTGBHU` have the same number of letters

Comment: This was my first thought, but I can't really think of a good reason why they would type a word with the same number of letters as the name of the killer.

Comment: @RothX Ikr, like if you're getting killed, you're not gonna go like 1...N...2...O...3...R...4...M...*AGGHHHHH (dies)*.

Comment: Blood loss, loss of vision... +1 from me

Answer (score 6):

> No Murder, since the N clue would be obvious. The police officer is a disguised detective, who is already suspecting you and waiting for your reaction.